# clear() does not work for erasing markers while using Google Maps API

Tags: api, kotlin, google-maps, location, markers

I'm using the Google Maps API in Kotlin and i'm trying to clear all the all ready generated markers from it before creating one of my own, but it doesn't seem to work.

The code is below:

```
        val mapFragment:SupportMapFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
    }

    override fun onMapReady(mapaCreado: GoogleMap) {
        mapaCreado.apply{
            mapaCreado.clear()

            val coordenadas = LatLng(37.37410286896958, -5.969290673333865)
            addMarker(
                MarkerOptions()
                    .position(coordenadas)
                    .title("IES NERVION")
            )
        }
        map = mapaCreado
    }
```

Comment: according to the docs, `.clear()` is how you do it. My bet is that your `onMapReady` function is not called when you think it is called, or not called at all. It might be worth adding a log there and running your code in debug to check if it does actually make it there.

Comment: Actually you're wrong, the mistake was thinking that the default labels that Google Maps API work as markers, the way of removing them is changing the Google Maps style via Google Maps Cloud Styling or a custom JSON file.

Comment: if you did find the solution, don't forget to add it as an answer here. You can even accept your own answer btw. It will help others that have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main reason code wasn't working is because .clear in Google Maps class does not refer to the actual markers that it has by default, but instead it refers to the one you create on it.

The markers the Google Maps has by default are refered to as labels, and must be removed via styling, either using Google Maps Cloud Styling (not free apparently) or by creating your own style with JSON and setting it.

```
[
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Then in your code.

```
setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this@MainActivity, R.raw.map_style));
```

Where R.raw.map_styles refers to the JSON file you created earlier.